# How to make single-multilevel convertible, keyborad accessible, non-javascript dependent (except IE), CSS sprite dropdown navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, accessibility

I've to write css for a simple/ horizontal menu for a CMS and i've to write css as if client will add subpages to main page and subpages of of subpages

I mean right now it's simple navigation no dropdown but in future it can single level dropdown or multilevel dropdown

and if navigation will have dropdown then dropdown links should be accessibile by keyboard also and it should work in all browsers without javascript except IE6 for IE 6 i will add javascript . I'm already using jquery on site for other things.

and i have to use css sprite for menu background image so if images is disabled then on menu link text should be shown as ALT text.

Is this possible make this type of menu with all these things?

Comment: You can't. If you want it to expand under keyboard access you need JavaScript. If you want it to expand sensibly under mouse access, you still need JavaScript to add a fuzz factor to make it accessible to people with motorskill related handicaps (such as those induced by arthritis. CSS is great for styling, but sucks for interaction logic which belongs in JavaScript. I'd avoid drop downs entirely on the WWW if possible though: http://message.uk.com/dropdown-menus-no-thanks/

Comment: if JavaScript is disabled then keyboard navigation on drop-down will not work , no problem but it should work if JavaScript is enabled. but if js is disabled then dropdown should work with mouse interaction

Comment: @David Dorward - +1 for good link

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your keyboard to access CSS-only menus without JavaScript. That's just not possible.

But, if you can live with that, I found tonnes of stuff [on google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enDK367DK367&q=css+only+dropdown+menu&btnG=S%C3%B8g) in an instance.
The first result shows some good examples of dropdown menus, but theres a *huge* amount of stuff out there.

Still, there are disadvantages, as you cannot make any delay *at all* when the user hovers the menu with the mouse. You'll need good ol' JavaScript for that, too.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: i know about css dropdown i'm not asking for simple drpdown  read my question andcomments properly

Comment: Then you should ask your question properly, in an understandable way. Because, as I see it, I *did* answer your question - NO, it's not possible. Thus, I don't like wasting my time on people not being thankful of me using my time on their problems.